# WebView in RecyclerView: match_parent vs wrap_content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-webview, android-support-library, android-viewholder

I would like to have WebView inside of RecyclerView.ViewHolder. Unfortunately, I find no good solution for getting right height of WebView.
Android Studio informs me that WebView requires from the parent layout to have layout_height="match_parent".

On the other hand, since Support library 23.2.0 RecyclerView takes into account ViewHolder's layout_height:

> RecyclerView.LayoutManager no longer ignores some RecyclerView.LayoutParams settings, such as MATCH_PARENT in the scroll direction.
>
> Note: These lifted restrictions may cause unexpected behavior in your layouts. Make sure you specify the correct layout parameters.

So because of that WebView has height much bigger than required.

One solution would be to downgrade Support Library.

Since I require only static web pages, I could also render WebView into some View that does not require parent's layout_height="match_parent".

Is there any other (clean) solution for that?

Comment: Did you actually _try_ to just use `wrap_content`?

Comment: Yes, wrap_content works fine on my phone with my current android version etc. but I am afraid that if Android Studio informs me that "Placing a <WebView> in a parent element that uses a wrap_content size can lead to subtle bugs; use match_parent", so I have no guaranty that my app will look good in other conditions good too.